What is the Django logic flow to show pdf inside HTML template after click the given link
I'm using Django to create a website to public my post, all of my post is pdf.
As usual, I defined my view and view logic, it returns a context dictionary
views.py

class PageView(TemplateView):
     def get_context_data(self):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        highlightObject = Post.objects.filter(is_highlight = 1).order_by('-created_on')
        context['highlight'] = highlightObject
        return context

Then, on my html file
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% for row in highlight %}
     <h3 class="mb-auto">{{ row. Title }}</h3>
       <div class="btn-group">
            <a href="{{ row.pdfFile.url }}" class="icon-link">Reading more</a>
       </div>
{% endfor %}


Until now, when cliking on the "Reading more", it changes to pdf Viewer, but I want to show pdf viewer inside html template, for example, it should change to other html file which extend the template from base.html and show pdf viewer using path row.pdfFile.url
So, how to write a new html file for reading pdf from directory row.pdfFile.url
Or, if there is any other way to solve this problem.
Thanks

Use an <iframe>.

Try with HTML <embed> tag like this


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        /* Style the button that is used to open and close the collapsible content */
        .collapsible {
            background-color: #eee;
            color: #181818;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 8px;
            width: 100%;
            border: none;
            text-align: left;
            outline: none;
            font-size: 15px;
        }

        /* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */
        .active,
        .collapsible:hover {
            background-color: #ccc;
        }

        /* Style the collapsible content. Note: hidden by default */
        .content {
            padding: 10px;
            display: none;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>
    {% for row in highlight %}
    <h3 class="mb-auto">{{ row. Title }}</h3>
    <button type="button" class="collapsible">Read more</button>
    <div class="content">
        <embed class="pdf" src="{{ row.pdfFile.url }}" width="800" height="500">
    </div>
    
    {% endfor %}
    
</body>
<script>
    var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
        coll[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            var content = this.nextElementSibling;
            if (content.style.display === "block") {
                content.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                content.style.display = "block";
            }
        });
    }
</script>

</html>



reference link here
Browser View

